# React navigation Header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react-native 0.62.0 with react-navigation version ^4.3.7 and createMaterialBottomTabNavigator. I have tried searching and implementing their solutions but none of it seems to work. I want to center the text in my header. This is what I tried.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Profile',
    headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', fontSize: 20, alignSelf: 'center' , },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#4169E1',
    },
})
```

Comment: did not work. and tried adding justifyContent:'center' still nothing

Comment: I have posted an example. It has full customization in the header.

Comment: Hi add this in style justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'

Comment: adding  justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'  still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Profile',
    headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', fontSize: 20, alignSelf: 'center' , },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#4169E1',
    },
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
})
```

Comment: its Horizontally center now but not vertically. No margin top.

Comment: headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' , textAlign:"center",flex:1 } should work

Comment: headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            alignSelf: 'center',
            textAlign:"center",
          },

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing `alignSelf: 'center' ,`. The below code is working for me.

```
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1e89f4'
          },
          headerTitle: 'Statistics',
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            flex: 1
          },
          headerLeft: (
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                size={25}
                color='#fff'
                icon={faBars}
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              />
            </View>
          ),
          headerRight: <View />
        };
      }
```

Comment: You are facing a problem with vertical alignment?

Comment: yes veritcal and horzontal Carlos Saiz Orteu answer solved the horizontal issue